# how to update xattribute values in an xelement where attribute is in list?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

Hello  I have an Xelement which looks like this:

```
dim elementfromwebservice as xelement=

<companies>
<address idstring=xxxx hasorder=xxxx </address>
<address idstring=xxxx hasorder=xxxx </address>
<address idstring=xxxx hasorder=xxxx </address>
</companies>
```

and I have which List which holds IDs here pseudosyntax:

```
dim listofid as (List of String) = new list(of string)
```

I want update all address.@hasorders attributes of elementfromwebservice 
where idstring is in listofid

I hope you can help

Chers steven

Answer (score 1):

Using VB.NET's support for XML, and a LINQ to XML query to find the elements you are interested in:

```vb
Dim elementFromWebService As XElement =
    <companies>
        <address idstring="xxxx" hasorder="xxxx"></address>
        <address idstring="xxxy" hasorder="xxxx"></address>
        <address idstring="xxxz" hasorder="xxxx"></address>
    </companies> 
Dim listOfId = { "xxxx", "xxxy" }
Dim addressesToUpdate =
    From e In elementFromWebService...<address>
    Where listOfId.Contains(e.@idstring)
For Each address In addressesToUpdate
    address.@hasorder = "updated"
Next
```

After this, `elementFromWebService` will contain:

```
<companies>
    <address idstring="xxxx" hasorder="updated"></address>
    <address idstring="xxxy" hasorder="updated"></address>
    <address idstring="xxxz" hasorder="xxxx"></address>
</companies>
```

Comment: Mark : This will not work because you are not updating values in original XElement, and you only have a portion of the original elements in your final results.

Comment: @jdweng Not sure what you mean - the relevant `XElement`s in `elementFromWebService` are updated directly by this code. `addressesToUpdate` contains references to a subset of the original `XElement`s, and being references, the original values are being updated.  The XML shown at the end of the answer is copied directly from `elementFromWebService.Dump()` in LINQPad, and shows that the result contains the original XML modified where the IDs matched.  Make sense?  You can copy the code into LINQPad to verify.  Let me know if I am not understanding something. :-)

Comment: I s addressesToUpdate a copy of the original XElement or is it linked to the original XElement?

Comment: @jdweng `addressesToUpdate` is an `IEnumerable(Of XElement)` of references to the original `XElements` that match the query.

Comment: I will check this, when I'm at work. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = _
        "<companies>" & _
        "<address idstring=""xxxx"" hasorder=""xxxx"" />" & _
        "<address idstring=""xxxx"" hasorder=""xxxx"" />" & _
        "<address idstring=""xxxx"" hasorder=""xxxx"" />" & _
        "</companies>"

        Dim addresses As XElement = XElement.Parse(input)
        Dim listofid As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        listofid.Add("xxxx")

        For Each address In addresses.Descendants("address")
            Dim idstring = address.Attribute("idstring")
            If listofid.Contains(idstring) Then
                address.Attribute("hasorder").Value = "new value"
            End If
        Next address

    End Sub
```